# Is there a command-line API or scripting interface for Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu, api

I've put some files on [Ubuntu One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_One), and amongst other things I'd like to be able to synchronise it from within [Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs), and script it with [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) or [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu One is built with CouchDB -- at least, that's what I gathered from [this Canonical presentation](http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/event/27/Building%20Applications%20Using%20Ubuntu%20One%20Presentation.pdf). You can find out more about the Desktop CouchDB project on their [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/desktop-couchdb/) page. More specifically, here's the [Google Code page for couchdb-python.](http://code.google.com/p/couchdb-python/)

Answer (score 2):

Actually Ubuntu One has many parts and the files stored in Ubuntu One are not part of CouchDB.

Recently a REST API was created to access the files in Ubuntu One. It is documented [here.](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

u1sdtool, but it seems to open x11 windows for things like authentication prompts, so not entirely commandline. I'm having trouble using it over ssh, even with x11 forwarding :-/